# error: can not use import outside a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module

I never used a module outside a boilerplate created by for example **create-react-app** or **angular-cli**, now i am trying to mimic modularity without using them, and i get an `error: cannot use import outside a module`

this is my `package.json` file:

```
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

I am using a live-server to create a server for my project, I am failing to do that:

**App.js**:

```
const x = 10;
export default x;
```

**index.js**:

```
import x from './App' // can not use import outside a module
```

The question is what i missing here, what do i really need to create a module??

Comment: Can you list your directory structure and how are you running the file ?

Comment: it is a simple project folder just contains an index.html, index.js file, app.js file, package.json, and how i run the project, it seems that i do no't know what should i do to run the project in a modularity system

Comment: Run your `index.js` file using `npx babel-node index.js` and see if that works. And make sure you have `.babelrc` file in the root of your project.

Comment: no it doesn't work and don't have ```.babelrc```  in the root